# Make short timelapse movie from long boring movie?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have an .mp4 file to turn into a timelapse movie.

How can I encode every `n` frames from the source movie into a new movie file, preferably using ffmpeg?  Solutions that extract a bunch of stills from the original and then re-encode are not OK, it will use too march hard disk space (but solutions that just use temporary images one by one and pipe them in are OK)

I found the following video filter:

`ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf select='not(mod(n\,25))' out.mp4`

But it seems to need tweaking, my output video is now still the same length but with a very slow framerate.

Comment: If neither slhck of lordneckbeard do it first, I'll probably write up an answer later today, but in the meantime you should take a look at the [select](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#select_002c-aselect) and [setpts](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#setpts_002c-asetpts) filters, and the notes on [expressions](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Expression-Evaluation).

Comment: I found some help here https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/How%20to%20speed%20up%20/%20slow%20down%20a%20video

Comment: you should write that up as an answer ;)

Comment: OK, I shall ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a complex filtergraph, you can speed up video and audio at the same time:

Factor of 2:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -filter_complex '[0:v]setpts=0.5*PTS[v];[0:a]atempo=2.0[a]' -map '[v]' -map '[a]' output.mkv
```

Factor of 4:

Using a complex filtergraph, you can speed up video and audio at the same time:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -filter_complex '[0:v]setpts=0.25*PTS[v];[0:a]atempo=2.0,atempo=2.0[a]' -map '[v]' -map '[a]' output.mkv
```

etc.

Comment: You can also use something like `setpts=(1/30)*PTS` (to speed up by a factor of 30) if you don't want to bother working out the decimal fraction yourself.

Comment: oh, thanks!  do you know how to match the atempo in the general case?  i think it only accepts values in range 0.5-2.0, but you can chain them in series as shown in my second example ..

Comment: no, unfortunately I don't know how to do that. The [documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#setpts_002c-asetpts) seems to imply that the `asetpts` filter should be usable in the same way as `setpts`, but I can't get it to work...

Comment: Well, I guess if the factor is (1/30) for video PTS then you need to chain together atempo 5 times with a value of the 5th root of 30  :)